# What's a terse es6 way of flattening a nested object?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

For example, turn this:

```
const enums = { ip: 'ip', er: 'er' };

const obj = {
  somethingNotNeeded: {...},
  er: [
    { a: 1},
    { b: 2}
  ],
  somethingElseNotNeeded: {...},
  ip: [
    { a: 1},
    { b: 2}
  ]
}
```

Into this:

```
[
  { a: 1},
  { b: 2},
  { a: 1},
  { b: 2}
]
```

I'm already doing this in a roundabout way by declaring an enum object of the types i want (er, ip) then doing a forEach (lodash) loop on obj checking if the keys aren't in the enum and delete them off the original obj. Then having just the objects I want, I do two nested forEach loops concatenating the results to a new object using object rest spread...

I'm almost entirely sure there's a better way of doing this but I didn't think of it today.

Comment: If you are already using lodash, then there is a better and cleaner way! if you are ok with that (using lodash) I can show you the simple way using lodash.

Answer (score 1):

Get the `enums` properties with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) (or [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) if they are always identical). Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the array of property names, and extract their values from `obj`. Flatten the array of arrays by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const enums = { ip: 'ip', er: 'er' };

const obj = {
  somethingNotNeeded: {},
  er: [
    { a: 1},
    { b: 2}
  ],
  somethingElseNotNeeded: {},
  ip: [
    { a: 1},
    { b: 2}
  ]
};

const result = [].concat(...Object.values(enums).map(p => obj[p]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const props = ['ip', 'er']; // An array of the properties you are interested in

const obj = {
  somethingNotNeeded: {},
  er: [
    { a: 1},
    { b: 2}
  ],
  somethingElseNotNeeded: {},
  ip: [
    { a: 1},
    { b: 2}
  ]
}

const flatten = (array) => array ? array.reduce((output, array) => [...output, ...array], []) : array; // Take an array of arrays and flatten it into a single array

const result = flatten(props.map(p => obj[p])); //Run the flattern over an array that has been created by mapping the property names

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using the `key` of the `enums` in the final output, we could simply use an `Array` instead of an object.

```
const enums = ['ip', 'er'];

const obj = {
  somethingNotNeeded: {},
  er: [
    { a: 1 },
    { b: 2 },
  ],
  somethingElseNotNeeded: {},
  ip: [
    { a: 1 },
    { b: 2 }
  ]
};

const result = enums.reduce((acl, curr) => acl.concat(obj[curr]), []);
console.log(result);
```

This should do the trick.